# Python - Matplotlib in Tkinter: The toolbar pan and zoom doesnt change the cursor

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I've been developing a tkinter app, which has a matplotlib graph embeded in it. The problem i am having right now is :

Allthough the functionality of the toolbar is working, it doesnt change the cursor which makes a worse user experience since you cant tell if you are zooming or not.
From what i have seen from various documentation and online tutorials this shouldnt be an issue.

From what i read, the toolbar should even makes changing cursor harder, since it overrides to cursor all the time when pan or zoom is selected. I am posting the related parts of my code, please let me know if you see something that doesnt add up, or anything that i might be missing.

Any suggestion is much appriciated!

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

class Controller(tk.Tk): 
    self.canvass = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.plots, self)
    self.canvass.show()
    self.canvass.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="news") 

    self.toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(self, width=410, height=30)
    self.toolbar_frame.config(relief="sunken", borderwidth=1)
    self.toolbar_frame.pack_propagate(flag=False)
    self.toolbar_frame.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky="w")

    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvass, self.toolbar_frame)
    self.toolbar.pack()
    self.toolbar.update()
```

**It turned out putting the toolbar into a frame causes that weird behavior. I just took a simple 'matplotlib in tkinter embedding' example which was working and modified it to use a frame as i did in my code, and the same problem occoured.**

I need the frame because normally the toolbar uses pack and i dont want to change the whole layout just because of this, since i'have used grid all along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have encountered the same problem too, and oddly enough this is caused by the canvas and the toolbar not having the same master.  Just making a new frame and putting the canvas and the toolbar in it will solve the problem. You still can place that frame with grid in your layout .